# sorting dates if timestamp is greater than zero

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm trying to sort dates from oldest to most recent but I want timestamps that are zero to be at the bottom of the sorted list. Only dates that are greater than zero should be sorted and at the top of the list.

The issue I have is that timestamps that are zero show up at the top... how do I ignore zero timestamps and put them at the bottom and give the timestamps that are greater > 0 priority on the list ?

Here's what I have:

```
        //DATE SORT
        self.tasklist.sort { $0.onsiteThreshold < $1.onsiteThreshold }
        self.tasklist.sort { $0.resolutionThreshold < $1.resolutionThreshold }
        self.tasklist.sort { $0.scheduleDateTime < $1.scheduleDateTime }
        
        self.tasklist.sort { (o1, o2) -> Bool in
            if o1.onsiteThreshold == 0 || o2.onsiteThreshold == 0 || o1.resolutionThreshold == 0 || o2.resolutionThreshold == 0 || o1.scheduleDateTime == 0 || o2.scheduleDateTime == 0 {
                return false
            }
            
            return true
        }
```

Comment: Are these actual `Date` types, and if so what do you mean by zero, or your own representation of a date?

Comment: @flanker These are integer unix timestamps (example: 1647266400000) .. some of these will have a timestamp value of 0 which means the date hasn't been set on that specific variable (onsiteThreshold / resolutionThreshold / scheduleDateTime) which is why it should be ignored and put at the bottom of the sorted list

Comment: I would sort the array **once** by all three criteria and than **stable partition** the array to move all items with zero values to the end. Or vice versa, first partition the array then sort the **slice** which contains the *`> 0`* items

Comment: @vadian can you please provide an example

Answer (score 0):

Sorting an array four(!) times is pretty expensive.

A more efficient way is first to move all items which contain zero properties to the end of the list with [`partition(by:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/3017524-partition). This API is part of Standard Library but doesn't preserve the order of the left side, therefore the partition must take place first.

```
let partitionIndex = tasklist.partition(by: {$0.onsiteThreshold == 0 || $0.resolutionThreshold == 0 || $0.scheduleDateTime == 0})
```

Then sort the *left side* `tasklist[0..<partitionIndex]` by all three properties and append the *right side*.

```
let sorted = tasklist[0..<partitionIndex].sorted { (lhs, rhs) in
    if lhs.scheduleDateTime == rhs.scheduleDateTime {
        if lhs.resolutionThreshold == rhs.resolutionThreshold {
            return lhs.onsiteThreshold < rhs.onsiteThreshold
        }
        return lhs.resolutionThreshold < rhs.resolutionThreshold
    }
    return lhs.scheduleDateTime < rhs.scheduleDateTime
}

taskList = sorted + tasklist[partitionIndex...]
```

Comment: This doesn't work... my logic is to just lhs < rhs for each date variable timestamps and put zero at the bottom of the list.

Comment: Yes, but this is what the code does. I tested it.